# How to Setup Laravel5.1 App on SharedHost?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.1, http-error, server-configuration

I'm trying to make my laravel5.1 application live on a sharedhost but I'm failing at it no matter how hard I'm trying.
my host structure is given at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqHq7.jpg).
The laravel application is under app folder and the content of public folder of laravel cutted to public_html.
at the index.php of public_html I have :

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Now I'm not seeing neither my index page nor watching any errors in /app/storage/logs/laravel.log .

by the way my .htaccess in public_html content is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create folder laravel in your root directory copy all data to that folder except public folder

then copy all data from public folder to folder pubic_html

now edit your index.php in your public_html folder like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then change `Config/database.php` and insert valid data for database connection

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

[image: Third step]

[Good tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it didn't worked!
it is still saying internal error without any logs!! :|

Comment: hmm i did everything step by step and this works for me on godaddy. I use shared hosting too

Comment: just to be sure, how laravel's storage `permissions`? it should be 775 (rwx rwx r-x). and before uploading, make sure no pre-compiled php left, use `php artisan clear-compiled`.

Answer (score 0):

Although [the answer from Adnan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34189726) can work. Is important to keep in mind that Laravel was not developed to work on a shared host.
Uploading the application folder in the root directory will expose also the configuration files.

This is a serious security problem and should be avoided!

Only the content of the 'public' folder (or/and resources if the view is there) should be in the root directory. All the other files must be placed outside the web root.

I also am aware that this is not so easy to do as seems to be.
But nowadays the security of your ad your customers data is more important than that!

That said, you can do of course whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your attention .so you say that move the content of laravel folder to a nested folder of laravel? such as /laravel/app1 ?

Comment: I see out the image you have posted that the Laravel application files are outside the public_html, so I guess they are also outside the web root. Your index file is in the public_html folder and this is also fine. Now the difficult part is to let the files work together as intended. This is not so easy to do and can not be explained here. I suggest you to make some research on google and see if you can find something. I can point you to some of them: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5.